# Запятая перед «как» (при описании действия)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в этом предложении?

*Дани **как** сидел, так и повалился на диван.*

Comment: Если в ответе есть полезная информация - можете поставить лайк - нажать на верхний серый треугольник. Если ответ решил проблему - поставить зелёную галочку (она может быть только у одного ответа). http://i.imgur.com/jnvr8HZ.png При этом отвечающие понимают, что не зря старались и что их ответ помог.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая перед "как" не нужна.

КАК.., ТАК И... — союз.

Запятая ставится только перед второй частью союза (перед словом «так»).

*Глянул дядя Зуй и **как** стоял, **так и** сел в снег.* Ю. Коваль, Стожок.
*Эта конференция собрала представителей **как** федерального, **так и** регионального уровня.*
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_352